# IP address location lookup using AWS Services

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, geolocation

I have a Java application running on AWS instances, and which uses the AWS SDK for Java v1.12.  I'd like to be able to lookup location information based on an IP address, such as city and state.  Does AWS provide this service?  If so, is there a basic Java example available somewhere?

Comment: There are many services that offer this, some even free.  AWS does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, AWS does not provide this service.

Answer (score 5):

While AWS does not offer it as a standalone service, if you only want to lookup the location of your calling clients, CloudFront CDN does offers extra headers you can use to achieve that.

For your use case you can have a look at:

- CloudFront-Viewer-Country
- CloudFront-Viewer-City
- CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region

ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-cloudfront-headers.html#cloudfront-headers-viewer-location

Answer (score 0):

While there is no first-party IP Geolocation service from AWS, Fastah API (I am the lead engineer) provides an [IP Geolocation API product on AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B084VR96P3) that you might find handy as it's a simple REST API with a JSON response that Java can trivially work with. The developer quick-start is [here](https://docs.getfastah.com/docs/quick-start).